# Parsing two files, and comparing strings

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

So I have two files, formatted like this:

First file

```
adam 20 male
ben 21 male
```

Second file

```
adam blonde
adam white
ben  blonde
```

What I would like to do, is use the instance of adam in the first file, and search for it in the second file and print out the attributes.

Data is seperated by tab "\t", so this is what I have so far.

```
$firstFile = fopen("file1", "rb"); //opens first file
$i=0;
$k=0;
while (!feof($firstFile) ) { //feof = while not end of file

$firstFileRow = fgets($firstFile);  //fgets gets line
$parts = explode("\t", $firstFileRow); //splits line into 3 strings using tab delimiter

$secondFile= fopen("file2", "rb");                          
        $countRow = count($secondFile);                 //count rows in second file     
        while ($i<= $countRow){     //while the file still has rows to search                       
            $row = fgets($firstFile);   //gets whole row                                
            $parts2 = explode("\t", $row);              
            if ($parts[0] ==$parts2[0]){                    
            print $parts[0]. " has " . $parts2[1]. "<br>" ; //prints out the 3 parts
            $i++;
            }
        }


}
```

I cant figure out how to loop through the second file, get each row, and compare to the first file.

Comment: If your first file is not large, I would suggest to read the first file into cache and then combine the second file's content into a maybe multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the inner loop, you are reading `firstfile` and should be reading second file. In addition, after exiting inner loop you would want to re-wind the `secondfile` pointer back to the beginning.

Comment: thanks for your help. Hadn't noticed that. I added $firstFileRow[]  instead of just $firstFileRow, and this has helped me to find a soloution. New to the site, so should i edit my question with soloution?

Comment: If your are happy that my answer solves your problem, please tick so that it appears answered. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
function file2array($filename) {
    $file = file($filename);
    $result = array();
    foreach ($file as $line) {
        $attributes = explode("\t", $line);
        foreach (array_slice($attributes, 1) as $attribute)
            $result[$attributes[0]][] = $attribute;
    }
    return $result;
}

$a1 = file2array("file1");
$a2 = file2array("file2");
print_r(array_merge_recursive($a1, $a2));
```

It will ouput the following:

```
Array (
    [adam] => Array (
        [0] => 20
        [1] => male
        [2] => blonde
        [3] => white
    )
    [ben] => Array (
        [0] => 21
        [1] => male
        [2] => blonde
    )
)
```

However this one reads both files in one piece and will crash, if they are large ( >100MB). On the other hand 90% of all php programs have this problem, since `file()` is popular :-)